# HttpCompileException was unhandled by user code. Error code: CS0433

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010

I GOT AN ERROR LIKE:

d:\Temp Works\31_1_2013\CRMEvent\CRMEvent\Views\CRMDashboard\RecentRequests.ascx(4): error CS0433: The type 'System.Web.Helpers.WebGrid' exists in both 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Helpers\v4.0_2.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.Helpers.dll' and 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Helpers\v4.0_1.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.Helpers.dll'

What this error means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your web config you have `<add assembly="System.Web.Helpers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />`. Try to change the version number to `2.0.0.0`

edit: Information on the web.config came from a question this user asked an hour ago on a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this error remove assembly from reference folder.